# On the essential infimum (over subdomains) of nonnegative measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis

let $\Omega:=\left(  a,b\right)  \subset\mathbb{R}$, and suppose
$f:\Omega\rightarrow\left[  0,\infty\right)  $ is a bounded (Lebesgue)
measurable function, with $f\not \equiv 0$ almost everywhere. It is *not* true
in general that there exists some interval $I\subset\Omega$ such that
*essinf*$_{I}f>0$.

My question is: is the assertion true adding the hypothesis
$|($supp $f)\setminus\Omega_{+}|=0$ ? Here, supp $f$ is the support of $f$,
$\Omega_{+}$ is the largest open subset of $\Omega$ where $f>0$ almost
everywhere, and $\left\vert Z\right\vert $ denotes the Lebesgue measure of
$Z\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Thanks in advance.

Uriel

Comment: How did this problem arise?

Comment: I want to extend a result I proved, from continuous functions to Lebesgue integrable functions. And I have used before this hypothesis on the support, so I thought it would help. Last but not least: it is not the first time I think about this, and I would like to know the answer, I think it is an interesting question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure one can find a function $f > 0$ almost everywhere, yet $\operatorname{essinf}_I f=0$ on every interval.  That would certainly be a counterexample since then $\operatorname{supp} f = \Omega_+ = (a,b)$

Comment: But this sounds a lot like what you already knew, so maybe you're not asking what I think you're asking...

Comment: Thanks Nate, you are absolutely right. The condition on the support does not bring anything new. And your example is correct, thanks again. Maybe I should ask the following: Under what conditions a nonnegative measurable function has an interval in which infess is positive there? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can construct a measurable $f$ with $f > 0$ almost everywhere yet $\operatorname{essinf}_I f = 0$ for every interval.  In particular we have $\operatorname{supp} f = \Omega_+ = (a,b)$.

Enumerate as $(q_n, r_n)$ the subintervals of $(a,b)$ having rational endpoints.  For each $n$, let $I_n$ be a subinterval of $(q_n, r_n)$ having length less than $1/2^n$.  Set $f_n = 1/n$ on $I_n$ and $1$ elsewhere.

Now let $f = \inf_n f_n$ which is certainly measurable.  Let $I$ be any subinterval of $(a,b)$.  Then $I$ contains infinitely many different subintervals having rational endpoints (note I do not require them to be disjoint), so for any $N$ there is $n \ge N$ such that $I_n \subset (q_n, r_n) \subset I$.  As such, we have $f \le f_n = 1/n \le 1/N$ on $I_n \subset I$, where $I_n$ has positive measure.  Hence $\operatorname{essinf}_I f \le 1/N$.  But $N$ was arbitrary so $\operatorname{essinf}_I f = 0$.

On the other hand, if $f(x) = 0$ then $x$ must have been in infinitely many of the intervals $I_n$.  Since $\sum m(I_n) \le \sum 1/2^n < \infty$, the Borel-Cantelli lemma says that the set of such $x$ has measure zero.  Thus $f > 0$ almost everywhere.